# Want to turn this pop-up effect into a Plug-in

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Here's a link to the to my fiddle with the example: http://jsfiddle.net/stavros917/AaQpZ/

So I have put together this effect and pop-up box that can be used for different things through out an application I'm working on with a team. I want this pop-up to be easily used through out the app, so I'm trying to turn it into a custom plug-in that the other devs I work with can use. I would like to be able to pass the function call some different values so that they are not having to re-create the html every time. Looking to do something along the lines of this when I call it:

```
$('popMe').popUp({
    headLine: 'headline text',
    buttonOneTxt: 'some text'
    buttonOneImg:  'foo.jpg'
    buttonTwoTxt:  'some more text'
    buttonTwoImg:  'img.jpg' 
});
```

Any help would be awesome! Still pretty new to making plug-in's so I'm a little stuck in how to approach this. I'm sure there are a lot of downloadable one's out there but I genuinely want to learn how it's done. Thanks again!

Comment: You want to create a jQuery plugin, or just a modular JS function?

Comment: This isn't a suitable question for Stack Overflow. Start [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) and try to build the plugin yourself, and ask a question if you get stuck.

Comment: Understood, I understand the process of turning it into a single function. Where I have trouble is setting up the custom arguments that I can pass it. For example the button images. I will continue to look it up though thanks.

Comment: Please see the Edit to my new comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to wrap everything in a simple command structure of

```
jQuery.fn.popUp = function () {
```

I've thrown it all together in a function you can reuse called popUp();. I didn't fix some erroneous calculation errors and re-run misnomers -- those are up to you. goodluck.

> http://jsfiddle.net/AaQpZ/1/

**EDIT 1**

Updated again to allow for dynamic fields to be populated. Please see the fiddle here, and scroll down the script to see how the a function invokes the HTML and passes it as parameters to the popUp() function.

> http://jsfiddle.net/AaQpZ/2/

**EDIT 2**

Sigh...I forgot to stop propagation and it was having appending issues on the close/enter functions. New code updated to stopPropagation() added...

> http://jsfiddle.net/AaQpZ/3/

Comment: Thanks! I had intended to wrap it in a function like that, just have trouble passing it custom arguments for the button text and what not. I will for sure be cleaning the code up for production as well.

Comment: Ah ok, I see how it works. I will play around with it some more, Should be able to get it to do what I need it too. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I think its still propagating actually.

Comment: Hey, sorry I had to step away for a few. In any event, the issue isn't propagation after all. I had kids screaming at me and wasn't thinking clearly. Our selector is "A" (at the bottom of the script), so we need to define something more specific like you had, $("a[name='modal']"). as it stands, all events fire on any Anchor click, so the close and enter buttons trigger our plugin as well. Sorry about that, good luck.